# Getting a PDO error when connecting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, localhost

So I'm working on my PDO skills and so far progress isn't so good. So here's the code corresponding to my issue.

`$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=s', 'root', '*');`

That's basically my connection to my database. Now here's the error I get

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I'm not sure why my access is being denied since the credentials are 100% correct. I've also tested that through the GUI for the database and was able to sign in successfully. Any ideas? I've also tried variables in the `username` and `password` section, but it didn't work nor does `127.0.0.1`. I'm on `localhost` on a Mac. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problems recently, what helped me was reseting my mysql root password:

First, login to user using mysql console:

```
mysql -u root -p[password]
```

(no space between `-p` and your password.
Then, type in command:

```
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE user='root';
```

Comment: This is what I get `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'sending authentication information', system error: 32` when typing the first code